# Joomla 2.5: GD Library - how to name the file to avoid conflict

Tags: php, joomla, gd, filenames

I'm writing a component for Joomla 2.5 that generates a graph using the PHP GD Library depending on the users input.

What name should I give the image file to avoid conflict when multiple users are using the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you have two way.
The first is save the image with prefix like this

```
scotttiger-img12321323.jpg
```

where *scotttiger* is the username and *12321323* is the user input.
Another way is to use different folder for every user

```
scotttiger/1231321.jpg
```

But if You don't have the user logged in and doesn't know the username, do a simple check with isfile (https://www.php.net/is_file) function and set incremental name. eg:

```
$wrote = false;
$prog = 0;
$filename="img-{$user_input}-{$prog}.jpg";
while(isfile($filename)) {
   $prog++;
   $filename="img-{$user_input}-{$prog}.jpg";
}
write_file($filename);
```

So you have the first time img-input-1.jpg the second once img-input-2.jpg and so on.
With this solution You doesn't have duplicates or conflict.

You can improve performance with this solution:

```
$wrote = false;
$prog = md5(time());
$filename="img-{$user_input}-{$prog}.jpg";
while(isfile($filename)) {
   $prog = md5(time());
   $filename="img-{$user_input}-{$prog}.jpg";
}
write_file($filename);
```

Comment: This approach could be slow, if you have many files the iteration can hog your script. Much better to have a random identifier appended to the image, and test if the file exists, with a couple of iterations you'll get your filename.

Comment: Yes, it can be improved with this assignment: `$prog = md5(time());`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you get stuck whit a bunch of files. Can I erase the files in some kind of __destruct in Joomla?

Comment: You can simple erase the file at the end of your process by do `unlink($filename)`.

Comment: Can you expand a bit the "end of your process" thing?

Answer (score 0):

you can generate random name with help of e.g. date and php hash function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

So the name will be unique.

Or, depends on used feature in your component, you can somehow add the user name to the image name. It depends of the function of the component and on my factors (if there will be only one image per user, or per some other feature, etc.)

Jan